# Move new files from dropbox as soon as they sync

Tags: windows, batch-file, dropbox

I use Dropbox (on my Windows XP and 7 PCs) as a way to get new iso files moved over to a directory on a computer at my home/office. I then have a Robocopy script that copies the files over from Dropbox into a folder, using the same file structure as the Dropbox folder. My question is this... is there a way to have the Dropbox folder checked/monitored, using either a script or some other software, and then run the Robocopy script to move the files out of the Dropbox folder to the local machine? I tried to use [Belvedere](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self%2bcleaning-pc&ei=o27xUdCkGebB0QXk2oGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNE4cQS-Xh9UrpYIawySlg9JgO8t_A&bvm=bv.49784469,d.d2k) to do this but what that does is run the Robocopy script I have on each file as opposed to just running it once because it has detected a new file.

I'm certain there will be a way to do this but I don't know what it is. Can anyone help?

The Robocopy script I use manually is here...

```
@echo off
rem  ©2007-2013 by http://www.iso.co.uk
cls
echo.
echo ======================================================================
echo File preparation script used to update newer iso stuff
echo =====================================================================
echo.

:start
echo.

pause
cls
cls
echo This shouldn't take too long...
echo.
echo.

Robocopy "C:\Documents and Settings\Home\Desktop\Dropbox\latest files\files\opensource" \\africa\iso_files\opensource /s /mov /zb

Robocopy "C:\Documents and Settings\Home\Desktop\Dropbox\latest files\files\cd-clock-it" \\africa\iso_files\cd-clock-it /s /mov /zb

Robocopy "C:\Documents and Settings\Home\Desktop\Dropbox\latest files\files\disc-phunk" \\africa\iso_files\disc-phunk /s /mov /zb

Robocopy "C:\Documents and Settings\Home\Desktop\Dropbox\latest files\files\disc-phunk" \\africa\iso_files\vvc /s /mov /zb

Robocopy "C:\Documents and Settings\Home\Desktop\Dropbox\latest files\files\disc-phunk" \\africa\iso_files\emac /s /mov /zb

cls

echo  The process has finished
echo.
echo  Press any key to exit this window and then remove your newly updated
echo  iso hard drive!
pause > nul
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went for was to adjust the above batch file so that there was no prompt to run the robocopy moves and no pause at the end of the file either. This was then scheduled to run each day (assuming the computer was on) at 17:00 but to only run after the computer was left idle for 3 hours as this is normally long enough for any new files to be downloaded from the dropbox server to the local dropbox folder on the machine.